# How to use value with placeholder

Tags: javascript, html

This code is showing 0 but i want show enter location with back end hidden value 0

```
<input type="text" name="location" value="0" placeholder="Enter Location" />
```

How to do this please help me to fix the small issue.

Thanks

Comment: If you got your answer : [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

The `value` attribute refers to the value inside the text-field.

The `placeholder` is only visible if the text-field has no value.

because of this there is no way to set the `value` attribute and still see the 
`placeholder`.

try using a custom attribute for your back-end code:

`data-value`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `value="0"` from your markup and it will work. `value="0"` is like you typed `0` into it, so it does not show the placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuntaly, any value added to the input, makes the placeholder dissapear. What you could do is add a value in the forms `onsubmit` handler if no value was entered

```
<form id="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Enter Location" />
</form>

<script>
    document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function() {
        var input = this.getElementsByName('location')[0];
        if (input.value.length === 0) input.value = '0';
    })
</script>
```

That way a zero is sent to the server if no value was inputted.
It would probably be easier to just check serverside if the input is part of the form data.

Comment: hi got error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Then your form doesn't have the correct ID, or you added the script before the form. Note that the code above works, as written only, and not for every conceivable form that doesn't match the selector

Comment: now i paste the script after the form and it is not showing any error but not working

Comment: And does your form have the id `myForm`, like the one in the code above has, and where `getElementById('myForm')` would get that form

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the solutions would be to put only the place-holder in the html & assign the default value in JS(if null).

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
    var input = $('#test').val();
    if(input == ''){
         $('#test').val('empty');
    }
    alert($('#test').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form> 
    <input id="test" type="text" placeholder="Type here" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try the above snippet? My snippet is working fine. Could you put up your code as a snippet, so that I can check.